# How to write Python custom library for Robot Framework for "doubleclick" and "find icon and type <some text>"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, robotframework

I am creating Robot Framework custom Library to do the following steps:

```
STEP 1 : click("firefox_icon.png")
STEP 2 : find("email_id.png"), and type("test@gmail.com")
STEP 3 : find("passwd.png"), and type( "test@123")
STEP 4 : doubleClick("signin.png")
```

Following is the test.robot file contents:

```
***Settings***
Library  calc.Calculator  WITH NAME  Calculator

***Test Cases***
Click Firefox Icon
    clickFirefoxIcon
```

Could anyone please guide me on how to write library for following functions:

1. Doubleclick on some icon(png file))
2. Find a "*.png" file, and enter some text (Example : Find E-mail ID png and type email address)

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE : We can use Selenium2 Lib to achieve this.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Could you please help me on this to write python function for double click and enter data part?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Selenium 2 library for what you want to do?

Let the Web driver open Firefox for you.

And you have keywords for locating the user and password fields.

Just look for Selenium 2 library login example